# How to run a mysql query in xammp on Windows 10 - I don't have the mysql password

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I run the command below, it is asking for the password. But I don't have the password for mysql. What should I do?

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p magento1.9 < magento_sample_data_for_1.9.0.0.sql
```

> Enter password: ***

Comment: Without you having the password, how do you think _we_ can help you? Do you think we can magically wipe out that question? It is your system, you know how you installed that package, you have the documentation.

Comment: If it is your system and if you are allowed to do it, you can just [reset your mysql password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html). If it is not your system, you have to ask the system administrator. Also, I would try the empty password first.

Comment: @arkascha , actually  phpmyadmin username is 'root' and password is null  ,  so when i going to run this query it's asking Enter passward  and i don't want  to set passward  so what should i do

Comment: `phpmyadmin` is a database _client_, it does define neither user account nor password. It mirrors what is defined inside the database management system, so the mysql server. If you say there is a `root` account _without_ a password (that is different from `NULL`), then fine, you have your answer. You simply do _not_ specify the `-p` flag in your query by which you explicitly tell the command line client you use to ask for a password. BTW, that is clearly explained in the commands documentation...

Comment: You should be able to find the database credentials in 'app/etc/local.xml'

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u root -p

source magento_sample_data_for_1.9.0.0.sql;
```

also you can exec `use db_name;` then run source command.

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup your magento already, you will be able to access your DB credentials in the following file 
`app/etc/local.xml`

look for the `<connection>` node e.g

```
<connection>
    <host><![CDATA[db]]></host>
    <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
    <password><![CDATA[root]]></password>
    <dbname><![CDATA[magento1]]></dbname>
    ...
</connection>
```